# Restart game after showing end screen

Tags: python, pygame

I'm creating a simple tic-tac-toegame with a little bit of support from [this page](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tic-tac-toe-gui-in-python-using-pygame/). I want to extend `reset_game()` to show the end screen for a few seconds and then reset the game. I do not understand how to handle time. `time.sleep` works when I want to wait 2 seconds before showing end screen, but it doesn't work when I want to show end screen, and then reset game. Here's my code:

```py
def reset_game():

    global winner, draw, main_board, XO

    time.sleep(2)
    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
    if winner:
        end_message = game_font.render(f"{winner} is the winner!", False, (0, 0, 0,))
        end_message_rect = end_message.get_rect(center = (width/2, (height/2)+50))
        screen.blit(end_message, end_message_rect)


    elif draw:
        end_message = game_font.render("Draw", False, (0, 0, 0,))
        end_message_rect = end_message.get_rect(center = (width/2, (height/2)+50))
        screen.blit(end_message, end_message_rect)

    winner = None
    draw = None
    XO = "X"
    main_board = [[None] * 3, [None] * 3, [None] * 3]
    game_initiating_window()
```

Comment: first you have to `blit()` (draw in buffer) and `update()` or `flip()` (send buffer to video card which will display it)  and later `sleep`

Comment: I don't see `pygame.display,update()` or `pygame.display.flip()` in code - so it doesn't send buffer to video card - and it can't display it on monitor.

Comment: Thanks, now after adding pygame.display.update() everything works correctly

Comment: I put it as answer below. If my answer helped then you can mark my answer as accepted (PL: jeśli moja odpowiedź pomogła to możesz ją oznaczyć jako zaakceptowaną)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to `blit()` (to draw in buffer), later you have to `update()` or `flip()` (to send buffer to video card which will display it) and later `sleep()`

```
def reset_game():
    global winner, draw, main_board, XO

    # draw in buffer

    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
    
    if winner:
        text = f"{winner} is the winner!"
    else:
        text = "Draw"
        
    end_message = game_font.render(text, False, (0, 0, 0,))
    end_message_rect = end_message.get_rect(center = (width/2, (height/2)+50))
    screen.blit(end_message, end_message_rect)

    # send buffer to video card - and it will display it on monitor

    pygame.display.flip()  

    # sleep
    
    time.sleep(2)

    # reset 

    winner = None
    draw = None
    XO = "X"
    main_board = [[None] * 3, [None] * 3, [None] * 3]
    game_initiating_window()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to put a `time.sleep` call before you reset the game:

```py
def reset_game():

    global winner, draw, main_board, XO

    time.sleep(2)
    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
    if winner:
        end_message = game_font.render(f"{winner} is the winner!", False, (0, 0, 0,))
        end_message_rect = end_message.get_rect(center = (width/2, (height/2)+50))
        screen.blit(end_message, end_message_rect)


    elif draw:
        end_message = game_font.render("Draw", False, (0, 0, 0,))
        end_message_rect = end_message.get_rect(center = (width/2, (height/2)+50))
        screen.blit(end_message, end_message_rect)

    time.sleep(3)
    winner = None
    draw = None
    XO = "X"
    main_board = [[None] * 3, [None] * 3, [None] * 3]
    game_initiating_window()
```

Comment: doing this way I can't see end screen, it goes straight to intro screen. I cant't figure why